# JQuery animate() function not working properly in Safari / Mac

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari, parallax

I am trying to create a site with lots of images sliding on click. Everything is fine except the fact that, it's not working properly in Safari browser.

Sample code is like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="left1" id="left"><img src="images/left1.png" ></div>
<div class="right" id="right"><img src="images/right1.png" ></div>
```

JQuery:

I want to slide these images on click of a link with class `in_home`.

```
$("a.in_home").click(function () {
        jQuery('#slider1 #right').stop().animate({ right : '-90%', 'margin-top' : '400px', 'margin-left' : '200px' });
        jQuery('#slider1 #left').stop().animate({ left : '-90%', 'margin-top' : '400px', 'margin-right' : '200px' });
        return false; 
    });
```

CSS

```
.left1 {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0px;
width:50%;
z-index: 2;
-webkit-transition:all 2.0s ease;
-moz-transition:all 2.0s ease;
-o-transition:all 2.0s ease;
transition:all 2.0s ease;
}
.right {
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:0px;
width:50%;
z-index: 2;
-webkit-transition:all 2.0s ease;
  -moz-transition:all 2.0s ease;
  -o-transition:all 2.0s ease;
  transition:all 2.0s ease;
}
```

Here is the demo link: 
http://qilolabs.com/karma_options/

Please suggest me how can i make it better.

Comment: You have to describe `not working` in question itself

Comment: it's not working properly in safari Wolff. I have mentioned that. I didn't understand your meaning.